# How to check access of user for particular user on object

Tags: permissions, sobject, user, schema, object

How do I check the access of current user on particular object dynamically.
I have a custom mapping object in that I am storing object name in the string.
I want to check Whether the current user has access to that object or not.
Like this

```
Schema.sObjectType.Account.isCreateable()
```

instead of account there can be any name.
like

```
Schema.sObjectType.customobject1.isCreateable();
Schema.sObjectType.customobject2.isCreateable();
```

& to convert I used this code

```
// I have Account name in String
String objectStr = 'Account';

// Convert to schema.sObjectType
Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr);
```

Still It is giving error like

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Schema.sObjectType.convertType.isCreateable()

Please Guide me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you are converting the `objectStr` value i.e `Account`, not the type of `Object`. Try with type of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT

I tried the below code for both standard and custom object and it is working in both cases for me. hope this helps.

**Standard Object**

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult drSObj = Schema.sObjectType.Account;
System.debug(drSObj.getChildRelationships());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfos());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfosByID());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfosByName());
System.debug(drSObj.isCreateable());
System.debug(drSObj.isAccessible());
System.debug(drSObj.isUpdateable());
System.debug(drSObj.isDeletable());
System.debug(drSObj.isFeedEnabled());
```

**Custom Object**

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult drSObj = Schema.sObjectType.Book__c;
System.debug(drSObj.getChildRelationships());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfos());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfosByID());
System.debug(drSObj.getRecordTypeInfosByName());
System.debug(drSObj.isCreateable());
System.debug(drSObj.isAccessible());
System.debug(drSObj.isUpdateable());
System.debug(drSObj.isDeletable());
System.debug(drSObj.isFeedEnabled());
```

**Updated Code**

Dynamically from  from Object Name

```
String objectStr = 'Account';
Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult drSObj = convertType.getDescribe();
System.debug('######'+drSObj.isCreateable());
```

Comment: can you add these two lines above the code

Comment: String objectStr = 'Account';

Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectStr);

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult drSObj = Schema.sObjectType.convertType;

Comment: See my updated code.